# Any tips or idea how to play this combinatorial game?

Tags: soft-question, game-theory, puzzle, combinatorial-game-theory, algorithmic-game-theory

There is this puzzle called Chomp. You can play and read about it here if you don't know it:

[https://www.math.ucla.edu/~tom/Games/chomp.html](https://www.math.ucla.edu/%7Etom/Games/chomp.html)

[image]

It is [well-known](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chomp#Winning_the_game) that Chomp has a winning strategy for the first player, except for the case of $1*1$. The proof is brilliant, but it is non-constructive, using a [strategy-stealing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strategy-stealing_argument) argument.

Imagine you are playing it with friends, who don't know about the winning strategy. He can be the first player, but he doesn't necessarily play the best move. Then, how should you respond? Is there a good strategy/heuristic to help us win?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't analyzed it for the strategy, but the page source on your link has the java script it uses to find moves:

```
var c=7;                //c = # columns.  Require 6 <= c <= 10.
var x,y;
var ppos=[1,12,23,34,45,56,113,122,224,235,246,336,355,1114,1125,1133,1222,2226,2255,2335];
    //perfect play for c=7 is achieved by adding 
    //67,257,347,477,2237,2357,2447,3377,3457,4557 to ppos. 
    //but ppos must be arranged in increasing order. 
    //For c=8, add 78,268,448,2248,2368,2458,2588,3338.
var n = [];
var box = [];

for (var i=1;i<=4;i++) {
    box[i]=[];
}

function yourChoice(u,v) {
    if (box[u][v]==1) {
        Move(u,v);
        encode();
        if (n[1]+n[2]==1) {
           alert("Good work!\n You won!");
           return;
        }
        x=findMove();
        Move(x,y+1);
        if (box[1][2]+box[2][1]==0) alert("Nice try,\n but I won!");
    }    
}

function Move(x,y) {
    for (var k1=x;k1<=4;k1++) {
        for (var k2=y;k2<=c;k2++) {
            document.images[(4-k1)*c+k2-1].src=blank;
            box[k1][k2]=0;
        }
    }
}

function encode() {               //maps position into n[1],n[2],n[3],n[4]
    for (var i=1;i<5;i++) {
        n[i]=0;
        for (var j=1;j<=c;j++) {
            n[i]=n[i]+box[i][j];
        }
    }
    n[1]=n[1]+1;
}

function findMove() {
    var t=10
    var k=ppos.length-1;
    for (y=n[1]-1;y>=n[2];y--) {
        val=y+t*(n[2]+t*(n[3]+t*n[4]));
        while (val<ppos[k]) k--;
        if (val==ppos[k]) {return 1};
    }
    for (y=n[2]-1;y>=n[3];y--) {
        val=n[1]+t*(y+t*(n[3]+t*n[4]));
        while (val<ppos[k]) k--;
        if (val==ppos[k]) {return 2};
        val=y+t*(y+t*(n[3]+t*n[4]));
        while (val<ppos[k]) k--;
        if (val==ppos[k]) {return 1};
    }
    for (y=n[3]-1;y>=n[4];y--) {
        val=n[1]+t*(n[2]+t*(y+t*n[4]));
        while (val<ppos[k]) k--;
        if (val==ppos[k]) {return 3};
        val=n[1]+t*(y+t*(y+t*n[4]));
        while (val<ppos[k]) k--;
        if (val==ppos[k]) {return 2};
        val=y+t*(y+t*(y+t*n[4]));
        while (val<ppos[k]) k--;
        if (val==ppos[k]) {return 1};
    }
    for (y=n[4]-1;y>=0;y--) {
        val=n[1]+t*(n[2]+t*(n[3]+t*y));
        while (val<ppos[k]) k--;
        if (val==ppos[k]) {return 4};
        val=n[1]+t*(n[2]+t*(y+t*y));
        while (val<ppos[k]) k--;
        if (val==ppos[k]) {return 3};
        val=n[1]+t*(y+t*(y+t*y));
        while (val<ppos[k]) k--;
        if (val==ppos[k]) {return 2};
        val=y+t*(y+t*(y+t*y));
        while (val<ppos[k]) k--;
        if (val==ppos[k]) {return 1};
    }
   if ((Math.random()>.4) && (n[4]>0)) {
       y=n[4]-1;
       return 4;
   } else if ((Math.random()>.5) && (n[3]>0)) {
       y=n[3]-1;
       return 3;
   } else if ((Math.random()>.67) && (n[2]>0)) {
       y=n[2]-1;
       return 2;
   } else {
       y=n[1]-1;
       return 1;
   }
}
```

Edit: Here are the winning 4 by 7 positions encoded or mentioned in the comment:

[image]

Comment: I've looked through it now, and it appears to just encode a list of winning positions, and a means of working out how to get to them. Apparently they intentionally left out some winning positions to give the player a chance to steal the win back. Still, I'll leave it up in case it is helpful to someone.

Comment: Thanks, Paul. Especially the pictures were really helpful.